Is there a good Hifz technique for me to memorize the Quran?
I want to memorize the whole Quran and I want a good memorization technique to memorize the Quran.
I really want to be one of the special people to Allah Azawajal, so how do I have a good memorization technique because the one Im using im not sure if it's good. The technique i use is repeat the first verse 15 and then once from memory and then i repeat the second verse 15 times and then once from memory and then i repeat the first and second verse 15 times and then once from memory and then so on and so forth
Jazakallah Khairn

Don't you think it's worth mentioning what technique you use actually is? Sometimes it's not a matter of technique but of the whole process and your daily habits... As for recommendations, I think I have mentioned some scattered in some of my answers.
